# Rashi Biographical Details

Tags: history, rashi, rishonim, tosfot

On Avodah Zarah 75a (dibur hamtchil "ולא פליגי"), Shabbos 85b ("בנוטה שורה לכאן ושורה לכאן"), Sukkah 40a ("ה"ג עצים דהסקה תנאי היא"), and Makkot 19b ("רישא במעשר שני טמא") there are personal comments by Rashi (or in the case of the Makkot source by his students) about Rashi's life, family, teachers, etc. Similarly on Brachot 25b ("והרי לבו רואה את הערוה"), Tosfot mentions Shemaiah, Rashi's student. Does anyone know of other such references in Rashi, Tosfot, or other Rishonim? Where do we learn about Rashi's birth city, family, children's names, etc.?

Edit: I found two more citations on Pesachim 76b ("אמר לך רב דכולי עלמא ריחא מילתא") and in Tosfot on Shabbos 54b ("רב"). The relevant lines and translations are as follows:

**Avodah Zarah 75a, Rashi ("ולא פליגי")**

> לשון אבא מורי מנוחתו כבוד והוא נראה בעיני והראשון לשון מורי וקשיא לי בגווה
>
> This is reading of my father, my teacher, may he rest in peace, and this seems to me [to be the correct reading]. The first reading [is that of] my teacher, and it is difficult for me since in the language of Sura, Rav and Shmuel certainly disagree (Sefaria translation).

**Shabbos 85b, Rashi ("בנוטה שורה לכאן ושורה לכאן")**

> כך נראית שיטה זו בעיני ולא פירשו רבותי כן שהם פירשו קרנות אלו גבולין ויש לי גמגומים בה הרבה גם בכל הש"ס לא שמעתי קרנות אלא זויות ומצאתי לי סמך ביסודו של רבי שמעון הזקן אחי אמי מפי רבינו גרשום אבי הגולה ותשובת רבינו יצחק בן יהודה שהושיבה בג' פנים לא ישרו בעיני
>
> This is how this *shita* appears to my eyes. And my rabbis did not expound thus. They expounded that *karnot* are "borders" and I have reservations in this [exegesis]. Further, in all *shas* I have not heard other than that *karnot* are "corners." And I found support [for my opinion] on the foundation of Rabbi Shimon HaZaken, my mother's brother, [who learned this] from Rabbenu Gershom, the Father of the Exile, and [in] the responsa of Rabbenu Yitchak ben Yehuda, who responded with three *panim* [i.e. interpretations]. It is not "straight" [i.e. clear] in my eyes.

**Sukkah 40a, Rashi ("ה"ג עצים דהסקה תנאי היא")**

> מצאתי גירסא זו בספר כתב ידו של רבינו גרשום בן יהודה מנוחתו כבוד ובסדר ישועות של רבינו יצחק בר מנחם
>
> And I found this version in a manuscript of Rabbenu Gershom ben Yehuda, may he rest in peace, and in "Seder Yeshuot" of Rabbenu Yitzchak bar Menachem.

**Makkot 19b, Rashi ("רישא במעשר שני טמא")**

> רבינו גופו טהור ויצאה נשמתו בטהרה לא פירש יותר מכאן ואילך לשון תלמידו ר' יהודה בר' נתן
>
> Our Rabbi, pure of body, died with his soul pure. He did not expound further than this point. From here on out, the language is that of his student Rabbi Yehuda bar Rabbi Natan.

**Pesachim 76b, Rashi ("אמר לך רב דכולי עלמא ריחא מילתא")**

> וכן הוא בתשובת הגאונים ואף משמו של רבי אליעזר בן יצחק
>
> And thus it is in the responsa of the Geonim, and even in the name of Rabbi Eliezer ben Yitzchak.

**Brachot 25b, Tosfot ("והרי לבו רואה את הערוה")**

> אלא דרבינו שמעיה תלמידו של רש"י פסק כת"ק
>
> But Rabbenu Shemaiah, the student of Rashi, *paskened* as the Tanna Kammah.

**Shabbos 54b, Tosfot ("רב")**

> כך קבל רבינו שמואל בשם רבינו שלמה ששמע מרבי אליעזר רבו
>
> Thus received Rabbenu Shmuel in the name of Rabbenu Shlomo who heard from Rabbi Eliezer his teacher.

All but the first translation are mine, so please comment and/or edit if I have misunderstood and words or phrases.

Comment: Maybe it would be good to include the translations of these relevant parts

Comment: Although a lot is based on circumstantial evidence and deduction from his and his contemporaries' writings - so, perhaps not so satisfying in terms of personal details - there are some interesting conclusions about Rashi, his principles, and his milieu in "[רש"י והמציאות ההיסטורית של זמנו](https://www.jstor.org/stable/i23585826)" and [_רש"י: תורתו ואישיותו_](https://simania.co.il/bookdetails.php?item_id=461755), if you're into that.

Comment: Much of what we know about Rashi is from his younger contemporaries, of which much is scattered throughout [Efraim Urbach](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephraim_Urbach)'s 'בעלי תוספות'. See also [Maurice Liber](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/liber-maurice)'s 'Rashi' for a fine objective biography.

Comment: Jews not Judaism? What does this have to do with Judaism besides being about an important Rabbi? If it was about his work, perhaps that would be on-topic, but I’m not sure if the fact that you’re looking for sources within said work is enough.

Comment: AZ 75 pretty much only tells us he had a father who died. Which isn't a big surprise.

Comment: @msh210 The acharonim have a debate based on that Rashi whether his father was a talmid chacham or not.

Answer (score 5):

Rashi in his commentary to the Talmud quotes his teachers dozens of times, but mostly without telling us their names. There are several instances, though, where he names people as his teachers, relatives, contemporary or near contemporary rabbinic figures. Sometimes he describes interactions with them, or rulings he received from them, or disagreements he had with them. It appears that the most mentioned figures are [R. Yaakov (Ben Yakar)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_ben_Yakar), R. Yitzchak Ben Yehuda, and R. Yitzchak Halevi, perhaps indicating that they were his primary teachers. Indeed, these three are listed as Rashi's teachers in the [Jewish Encyclopedia](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/12585-rashi-solomon-bar-isaac):

> As a matter of fact, however, Rashi merely studied at Worms for a
>   time, his first teacher being Jacob b. Yaḳar, of whom he speaks with
>   great veneration. After Jacob's death his place was successively
>   filled by Isaac ben Eleazar ha-Levi, or Segan Lewiyah, and by Rashi's
>   relative Isaac b. Judah, the head of the school of Mayence, a school
>   rendered illustrious through R. Gershom b. Judah (the "Light of the
>   Exile"), who may be regarded as Rashi's precursor, although he was
>   never his teacher.

Here are some of the passages from Rashi's commentary that mention specific people:

**[Shabbos 12b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=12b&format=pdf)**

> ומשום רבינו יעקב

**[Shabbos 23a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=23&format=pdf)**

> ומצאתי בשם רבינו יצחק בן יהודה שאמר משם רבינו יעקב

**[Shabbos 80b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=80b&format=pdf)**

> כן לשון מורי הזקן מפי אביו ששמע מר' שמעון ורבותי מפרשים

**[Shabbos 85b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=85b&format=pdf)**

> ולא גזר שמואל שמא ימלא את הקרנות כך נראית שיטה זו בעיני ולא פירשו
>   רבותי כן שהם פירשו קרנות אלו גבולין ויש לי גמגומים בה הרבה גם בכל
>   התלמוד לא שמעתי קרנות אלא זויות ומצאתי לי סמך ביסודו של רבי שמעון הזקן
>   אחי אמי מפי רבינו גרשום אבי הגולה ותשובת רבינו יצחק בן יהודה שהושיבה
>   בשלש פנים לא ישרו בעיני

**[Pesachim 48b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=48b&format=pdf)**

> וכן הורה לנו רבינו יעקב בן יקר

**[Yoma 16b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=6&daf=16b&format=pdf)**

> פירש לי מורי צדק רבינו יצחק בר יהודה ז"ל

**[Succah 35b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=7&daf=35b&format=pdf)**

> זה לשון מורי הזקן רבינו יעקב אבל רבינו יצחק הלוי היה מפרש

**[Succah 40a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=7&daf=40&format=pdf)**

> ואני שמעתי מרבותי שהיו גורסים וסתם עצים להסקה נינהו תנאי היא וכן כתוב
>   בכל הספרים וטרחתי מנעורי בכל צידי שיטת התלמוד לישבה כפי דבריהם ואיני
>   יכול ומצאתי גירסא זו בספר כתב ידו של רבינו גרשום בן יהודה מנוחתו כבוד
>   ובסדר ישועות של רבינו יצחק בר מנחם כתוב ואינו מוגה וכן נראה בעיני

**[Succah 45b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=7&daf=45b&format=pdf)**

> כן מצאתי ביסודו של רבינו יעקב

**[Beitza 24b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=8&daf=24b&format=pdf)**

> ולא זכיתי לשאול את פי רבינו יעקב בדבר זה כי היו נוהגים בו היתר
>   במקומינו והיה לי דבר פשוט ולאחר פטירתו של רבי שמעתי את רבינו יצחק הלוי
>   שהוא אוסר עד ליל מוצאי יום טוב שני וכל אנשי עירו כמותו וגם הלכות
>   גדולות אוסרים כן ודנתי לפניו ולא הועיל לי הדבר וכל טעמו אינו אלא מדנקט
>   בכדי שיעשו בלילה הראויה לעשיה קאמר ואני אומר צריך להמתין בכדי שיעשו
>   משום שמא היום היה קדש והלילה חול ותדע מדלא קאמר לערב של שני אסורים
>   בכדי שיעשו לערב הראשון קאמר ובתשובת רבינו גרשום מאור הגולה מצאתי כמותי
>   גם עתה בא אלי מכתב מגרמיי"ש שבא לשם אדם גדול זקן ויושב בישיבה מן רומא
>   ושמו רבי קלונימוס ובקי בכל התלמוד והורה כן ונחלק עליהן

**[Rosh Hashanah 28a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=9&daf=28&format=pdf)**

> כך שמעתי מפי מורי הזקן וביסודו של מורי רבי יצחק בן יהודה ראיתי

**[Rosh Hashanah 32a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=9&daf=32&format=pdf)**

> ולא שמעתיה אלא ראיתיה ביסוד רבינו יצחק בן יהודה

**[Megilla 26a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=26&format=pdf)**

> ובתלמידי רבינו יצחק הלוי מצאתי

**[Gittin 59b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=19&daf=59b&format=pdf)**

> כך אמר מורי הזקן ומורי ר' יצחק בן יהודה וכן סידר רב עמרם אבל מתלמידי
>   מורי רבי יצחק הלוי שמעתי משמו

**[Kiddushin 39a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=20&daf=39&format=pdf)**

> כך השיב רבינו גרשם בר' יהודה זצ"ל

**[Sanhedrin 97b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=97b&format=pdf)**

> מצאתי כתוב בשם הרב רבי שמואל בר דוד זכרונו לברכה

**[Zevachim 45b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=29&daf=45b&format=pdf)**

> וכך שמעתי מבית מדרשו של רבינו יעקב

**[Chullin 10b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=31&daf=10b&format=pdf)**

> ועל ידי היה מעשה והורה לי רבינו יעקב ב"ר יקר בעוף לאיסור

**[Temurah 4a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=34&daf=4&format=pdf)**

> ולא מפי מורי אלא מפי ר' יצחק בר' מנחם ז"ל

Answer (score 1):

This is a very intriguing question.

I looked at the [biography of Rashi](http://a.co/4JkDJoE) written by [Yaacov Dovid Shulman](https://www.shulman-writer.com/), he brings a few historical anecdotes with sources (e.g., on the lack of texts: "R Eliezer Hagadol was not able to learn Avoda Zara because there was no copy available to him (Teshuvot Chachmei Tzarfat 84)") but none regarding his life, family or teachers.

However in the introduction he quotes a number of *sefarim* he used to prepare his - maybe some of those are on hebrewbooks and will have further details

- R Eliezer Meir Lipschitz: Rashi - Rabbi Shlomo Yitzchaki
- Heichal Rashi
- Kovetz Rashi
- Sefer Rashi

I have also asked the author directly for more clues, and will update when he responds.

Comment: Thanks. Have you read Avraham Grossman's "Rashi"? Is Eliezer HaGadol the Eliezer ben Yitchak who seems to have been a student of R' Gershom and whom Rashi cites?

Comment: @MiYavin no I haven’t yet